# The RGB or html color of paper

Tags: colors

I am trying to find the color of paper from a paperback novel. Maybe it is a stupid question but I am working on a program in my spare time that provides a large number of pages for a user to read through and am looking for the comfortably familiar color of a well worn paperback novel. My scanner seems to bleach the pages I have tried to sample. (looking for a sheepish emoticon right now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't a single color that matches a paperback novel -- a gradient or textured pattern would be better to get the effect you are looking for.  (Although, speaking only for myself -- I find that plain black text on a white background to be the easiest to read on the screen or off of it.  The font face makes a greater difference than the background color, IMHO.)

Comment: I will definitely look into the gradients.  I have never had much success with tiles and textures and I hate black against white, it burns my eyes! ;) thanks though

Answer (score 4):

Try using `background:url('image_name.png');` with a pattern image from [SubtlePatterns](http://subtlepatterns.com).

Answer (score 3):

A scanner will automatically change the white balance.Try taking a photo of a sheet of paper out in the sun. Set your white balance to sunlight; don't use auto white balance. Then read that in with Photoshop or [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html) or something and use the eyedropper tool.

As for paper color as a concept, there's a parameter called paper brightness, which I absolutely don't understand:

http://www.axiphos.com/BrightnessReview.pdf

My parents are in the print business, and yeah, there are a myriad of paper colors out there that tend to change the mood of the book as well as the aging characteristics. On screen though, I think it'll invariably have a cartoonish effect -- which is good if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't know if I ever really wanted to understand the reasons behind brightness: 98 on a package of paper but that pdf was definitely interesting. +1 if I could

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "color of paper". What color the paper appears as depends on how it was manufactured, how old it is, if it's been left in the sun, if it's been sitting open collecting dust, how many times you've spilled coffee on it, and more.

I think rather than trying to find the exact RGB color value for "paper", you should do one of:

1. White. It's easy to read.
2. Light tan, and include some sort of rough-edge image border. You'll at least send the impression of paper.
3. Tile a background image of some paper texture. So long as the source is large enough and tiles well, it ought to look okay.

Answer (score 1):

i've found a hexadecimal colour code that comes the most close to that of paper.
try out #cb6

Answer (score 0):

Try out [#E0C57F](http://www.color-hex.com/color/e0c57f). I find that to be an even better approximation than #CB6 for me.

Comment: Maybe every screen is different. That colour looks absolutely nothing like 'paper white' on my screen. More like pale tea!